# Did Allah arrange or choose what type of life we would have?

Tags: qadar

Did Allah pre-plan or write our lives before we were born? For example, places we would visit, jobs, friends, etc.

Comment: Why did you have the tag 'tafseer'?

Answer (score 2):

[Predestination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_in_Islam) (قدر "qadar") in Islam is one of the [six articles of faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iman_(concept)#The_Six_Articles_of_Faith) necessary to be a Muslim.

> Indeed, all things We created with predestination.
> <sub>[Qur'an 54:49](https://quran.com/54/49)</sub>

And yes, there is a record, which predates the creation of Earth:

> Do you not know that Allah knows what is in the heaven and earth? Indeed, that is in a Record. Indeed that, for Allah, is easy.
> <sub>[Qur'an 22:70](https://quran.com/22/70)</sub>
>
> Allah ordained the measures (of quality) of the creation fifty thousand years before He created the heavens and the earth, as His Throne was upon water.
> <sub>[Sahih Muslim 2653 b](https://sunnah.com/muslim/46/27)</sub>

In general, Muslims believe humans have free will ([Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/96978)).  Many decisions are made for us, e.g., we didn't choose to breathe air, have red blood, live on Earth, or what our skin color is.  However, we are capable of choosing to sin, which we are punished for.  Importantly, in order to sin, we must be capable of choosing not to sin:

> (' Abd al-Wahhab Khallaf:) Three conditions must exist in any act that it is legally valid to make an individual responsible for. ...
>
> The third condition is that **the act the subject is responsible for be possible and within the capacity of the subject to do or to refrain from**.
>
> <sub>*The Reliance of the Traveller*, by Ahmad ibn Naqib al-Misri, translated by Nuh Ha Mim Keller</sub>

Thus, Muslims believe that Allah is aware (in advance) of what places we will visit, etc., while we have the ability to make decisions (and in particular, whether or not to sin).

Precisely how free will and predestination fit together is complicated and philosophical, which I'd like to avoid.  See e.g.:  1. [What is the role of free will in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1506/17163)  2. [Are humans destined to do things or human do things cause of free will?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12167/17163)  3. [How is there a fixed destiny if we have free will?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/18889/17163)  4. [How is free will in humans logically justified?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10585/17163)

Comment: Is it 'Free-will' or 'The Freedom To Chosen'? I mean I can will to have the sun rise from the west but the sun will still rise from the east. Whereas I can choose whether I want to see the sun rise or not. i.e I can chose from the set of options that are (on the surface) under my control.